# Problem with old ConTeXt separated list example

Tags: context, context-mkiv, comma-separated-list

I have been trying to get the following small example from [ConTeXt garden](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/csv.pdf) to work without success.

```
\starttext
\usemodule[database]

\def\SendMe#1#2#3#4{\framed
[align={flushleft,lohi},
width=4cm,
height=2.5cm]{#1\crlf#2\crlf\crlf\uppercase{#3\crlf#4}}}

\defineseparatedlist[Address][separator={;},command=\SendMe]
\startAddress
NTG;Maasstraat 2;NL-5836 BB Sambeek;The Netherlands
Dante~e.V.;Postfach 101840;D-69008 Heidelberg;Germany
\stopAddress

\stoptext
```

Context throws me with this:

```
...
resolvers       > modules > loaded: 'database'
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/m-database.mkiv<+ /usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/m-database.lua>)
! Argument of \SendMe has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   }
\doprocessdatabase ...rameter \c!command \!!es , }
                                                  }
l.13 \stopAddress

?
```

Unfortunately currently I don't have the opportunity to test this with the 
latest and greatest ConTeXt/LuaTeX packages. My versions are: ConTeXt 2012.05.21 23:16 and LuaTeX beta-0.71.0-2012050800 (rev 4406).

So is the example outdated (it is from 2006) and how this should be accomplished now? Or is this some regression bug with ConTeXt/LuaTeX? Or maybe someone can confirm that this indeed works with the very latest builds?

Comment: you can run it with mkII: `texexec <file>` then it works.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks for pointing out. Somehow it did not cross my mind to test it with the mkII. Now there is still the question should it work with the mkIV.

Comment: the mkiv version of m-database works only with settings like `command=\framed`. The documentation inside the module refers only to tables created from a csv list.

Answer (score 5):

you can run it with mkII: `texexec <file>` then it works.

the mkiv version of m-database works only with settings like `command=\framed`. The documentation inside the module refers only to tables created from a csv list.